# How to avoid resume after taking picture in android acera500 tablet

Tags: android

How do I avoid resume after taking picture in android? I didn't override any resume method. I am capturing pictures using the default camera in android. After the `onactivityresult` method is executed, it will refresh the activity. How do I avoid that? Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not.   This is part of activity lifecycle.  When you call camera (activity),   it comes to foreground,  and caller activity loses focus - wham,   onPause() is called.
When camera is done, it gives away focus and some other activity (yours) becomes it - wham, onResume() is Called.

You will have to work around this lifecycle.   What is your problem?

Comment: pribudal  I have two button in activity edit and done if user click edit only i am allowing capture camera after that done only it will update in webservice .after camera activity it will refreshing without updating the information

Comment: if user click edit button i have to show done button only but it will show two button edit and done button

Comment: this is completely different question

Comment: pribudla this is same question in my activity i have two button edit and done button .if user click edit button.we activate camera image button e and edit profile and if user click  camera button at the time i show only done button only.after user capture image activity is refreshing it show two button